# Bayesian Statistics: Simulate in R, the experiment described above 10,000 times and each time note the length of the longest run

Tags: r, bayesian, naivebayes

I'm trying to find the average of the longest run in 10,000 simulations when flipping a coin 30 times. I need to simulate in R, the experiment described above 10,000 times and each time note the length of the longest run.

Here's my code so far:

```
coin <- sample(c("H", "T"), 10000, replace = TRUE)
table(coin) 
head(coin, n = 30)
rle(c("H", "T", "T", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "T", "H"))
coin.rle <- rle(coin)
str(coin.rle)
```

## How to find the average of the longest run in 10,000 simulations?

Comment: When you enter code into a question, try adding four spaces before each line so that it formats nicely (or highlight the code and press Crtl+K, or click the `{}` button in the editor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the coin flips are independent of one another (i.e., the outcome of one flip does not influence another flip). Because of this, we can flip all of the coins for all the simulations at once and then format in such a way that will make it simpler to summarize each 30 flip trial. Here is how I would approach this.

```
# do all of the flips at once, this is okay because each flip
# is independent
coin_flips <- sample(c("heads", "tails"), 30 * 10000, replace = TRUE)

# put them into a 10000 by 30 matrix, each row
# indicates one 'simulation'
coin_matrix <- matrix(coin_flips, ncol = 30, nrow = 10000)

# we now want to iterate through each row using apply,
# to do so we need to make a function to apply to each
# row. This gets us the longest run over a single
# simulation
get_long_run <- function(x) {
  max(rle(x)$length)
}

# apply this function to each row
longest_runs <- apply(coin_matrix, 1, get_long_run)

# get the number of simulations that had a max run >= 7. Divide this
# by the number of simulations to get the probability of this occuring.
sum(longest_runs >= 7)/nrow(coin_matrix)
```

You should get something between 18-19%, but this will vary a little bit for each time you try this simulation.

Answer (score 2):

I  think the following does what you are after.

```
n_runs <- 10000
max_runs <- numeric(n_runs)
for (j in 1:n_runs) {
 coin <- sample(c("H", "T"), 30, replace = TRUE) 
 max_runs[j] <- max(rle(coin)$length)
}
mean(max_runs)
```

For an explanation of the code best to inspect a small segment of `coin` (like `coin[20]`) and the `rle` of it (`rle(coin[20])`). Lengths are computed for each segments of runs, so the `max(rle(coin)$length)` gives the max run.

EDIT: Following could be faster

```
len <- 30
times <- 10000

flips <- sample(c("H", "T"), len * times, replace = TRUE) 
runs <- sapply(split(flips, ceiling(seq_along(flips)/len)),
                    function(x) max(rle(x)$length))
mean(runs) # average of max runs
sum(runs >= 7)/ times # number of runs >= 7
```

Comment: How would I find the probability of getting a run of 7 or more in 30 coin flips based on your simulation?

Comment: Each simulation is 30 flips, not 10000. This code will get you the max length from 5 simulations that flipped a coin 10000 times.

Comment: @CABurns you can sum  `any(rle(coin)$length >= 7)` over the simulations. (A sequence with more than one 7 or more runs would be counted as one with this method.)

Comment: One more tiny thing, the fifth line of code has `maxs_rusn` instead of `max_runs`.